# Convert an Excel xls file to any XML format on unix?

Tags: xml, linux, excel

I receive an `xls` file (yes, with multiple sheets) regularly and have a whole bunch of business logic to apply on it. What I do *not* want is to have to use a 3rd-party library and then use library-specific commands like `sheet.cell(42,73)` mixed with the business logic all over the place. When the 3rd party lib expires, or Excel is updated, then everything would have to be engineered again.

Thus, I'd like to have a slim **xls-to-XML** transformation phase. The XML-dialect does not really matter, "xmlx" would do, Open-Office, Open-Doc, whatever. It just has to be well-defined. If there are changes in this transformation later on, I hope I can handle that with a small xslt.

In that XML I will write the business logic with the shipped xml-tools of my favorite language (python or perl), or even just xslt.

**What is the *most reliable*, *slimmest* way to transform an `xls`-file to an `xml`-file, on a Linux machine?**

Notes:

- The file contains multiple sheets, if this weren't the case I would ask for the simplest converter to csv.
- The machine will be be 64- or 32 bit, but will not have any way to connect to a Windows-machine.
- I would rather not have to install an Office on that server, i.e. for scripting Open- or Libre-Office...
- Alas, I can not ask that the file is saved in any other format, like `xlsx`. *sigh*

Comment: Will it be of any help for you to export that .xls file to .xps(XML Paper Specification (XPS)) file. There is just a simple way to that? Just a thought?

Comment: Nope, I asked the provider of the file, there is no way they can export it in any different format. But I note down the `xps`-format hint, if you have good experiences with that as a stable data exchange format.

Comment: Than, will this be of any help?
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/b6e8a28c-6760-4e86-a1aa-e2ce9ec36380

Read the Excel file into a DataTable and use DataTable.WriteXml().

Comment: Installing C#/Mono and a Jetdb-odbc connector...? Err... ok, the C#/Mono must have a way to read Excel then. Or is it the Jetdb-part? Hrmm...

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of retrieving data from Excel using JETDB, that I found on net:

```
        string connstr ="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.Oledb.4.0;Data Source=C:\aaa.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"/>
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connstr);
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet$]";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```